# Divide values of rows based on condition which are of running count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Sample of the table for 1 id, exists multiple id in the original df.

| id | legend | date | running_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | X | 24-07-2021 | 3 |
| 101 | Y | 24-07-2021 | 5 |
| 101 | X | 25-07-2021 | 4 |
| 101 | Y | 25-07-2021 | 6 |

I want to create a new column where I have to perform division of the running_count on the basis of the id, legend and date - (X/Y) for the date 24-07-2021 for a particular id and so on.

How shall I perform the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is same order `X, Y` for each `id` is possible use:

```
df['new'] = df['running_count'].div(df.groupby(['id','date'])['running_count'].shift(-1))

print (df)
    id legend        date  running_count       new
0  101      X  24-07-2021              3  0.600000
1  101      Y  24-07-2021              5       NaN
2  101      X  25-07-2021              4  0.666667
3  101      Y  25-07-2021              6       NaN
```

If possible change ouput:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index=['id','date'], columns='legend', values='running_count')

df1['new'] = df1['X'].div(df1['Y'])

df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
legend   id        date  X  Y       new
0       101  24-07-2021  3  5  0.600000
1       101  25-07-2021  4  6  0.666667
```